# BIRT fontsConfig.xml font issue

Tags: unix, fonts, birt

I working with BIRT 2.6 on a Unix machine, therefore I have problems to write a certain font.

I known I must edit the fontsConfig.xml file. But it didn't work: In short I have done this:

```
<fonts>
<font-aliases>
    <mapping name="Arial Narrow" font-family="LiberationSansNarrow-Regular" />
</font-aliases> 
<font-paths>
    <path path="/../../../fonts" />
</font-paths>
</fonts>
```

Is this configuration right? Is something missing/wrong?

At all there are four config xml's:

- fontsConfig.xml
- fontsCconfig_pdf.xml
- fontsConfig_win32.xml
- fontsConfig_linux.xml

Must I need to change all files, without the win32 file?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of handling the problem:

1. Modify existing fontsConfig.xml
   ---To do this: follow the guidelines provided in the documentation of fontsConfig file. Also, in order to jar/unjar fontsConfig, follow this post : [To Jar/Unjar fontsConfig.xml](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php/topic/28406-fonts-rendered-different-when-generating-pdf-report/)
2. Create your new fontsConfig.xml and pick that from a specific location of your choice.
   ---To do this, you can call the engineConfig's setconfig and pass the full file path.

   config.setFontConfig(fontConfig files URL in file://abc/abc);
3. Add fonts to your project path and pick that from the code using system properties.
   --- To do this, call the following.

   FontFactory.registerDirectory( scContext.getRealPath("full folder path") );

This should solve the problem