# BIRT report PDF font

Tags: pdf, fonts, birt

I am trying to embed a font in my BIRT pdf export. I am running the report from my webserver in the `Tomcat/webapps/birt` dir.

I checked the Fontsconfig.xml which points to the dir path

```
<path="/usr/share/fonts/default/TrueType" />
```

I have created the dir on my server as `usr/share/fonts/default/TrueType` and placed the (.ttf) font that I use in the report. I have updated my fonts cache via `sudo fc-cache -fv`, and I have restarted Tomcat. However, when I export my report to PDF form, the font does not get not used in the pdf.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean when you say you have "placed the font in the report"?

Comment: Hi Mike,I mean that I have set all fields in the report to the disired font..

Comment: worth explaining in the question how you did that, with some copy-pasting of what you're doing (not retyping!) because typos are super easy to miss when you've been staring at a problem for too long, but caught pretty much instantly the moment you show other people.

Comment: Hi Mike,sorry for the unclear info. I mean that for each field in the report in the property box, I have selected the font. When I run the report in the birt viewer, it shows the report in the disired font. However when I export the report to pdf it shows all info in the default font.. Hope its clear now..

Comment: did you make sure to explicitly pick the fontsConfig.xml file? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456048/birt-fontsconfig-xml-font-issue has some tips)

Comment: Hi Mike, as I understand the fontsConfig.xml file is on my local machine in the eclipse plugins folder. However the file is embedded on the production server in the jar file?? I have checked the file on my local machine from which I am developing the report. I did not configure or edited the file on my production server. Got no idea how to substract the fontsConfig.xml from the jar file and how to write it back once edited.. Or am I missing the point completely??

Comment: The article http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php/topic/28406-fonts-rendered-different-when-generating-pdf-report/ linked from the SO tips answer has some steps to follow in order to get a fontsConfig.xml that should work, so maybe worth running through them and see if that does it. If not, you can explain in your post that you already tried that approach but it didn't, and that'll help others determine what to suggest or post as answer.

Comment: tnx I will run trhough the articles..